# SQL SERVER: concatenate node values of XML column

Tags: sql-server, xml, concatenation, stuff

I have the following table that holds a column which is in XML:

| Id | Label | Details |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Test1 | `<terms><destination><email>email11@foo.com</email><email>email12@foo.com</email></destination><content>blabla</content></terms>` |
| 2 | Test2 | `<terms><destination><email>email21@foo.com</email><email>email22@foo.com</email></destination><content>blabla</content></terms>` |

I would like a query that produces the following output:

| Id | Label | Destination |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Test1 | `email11@foo.com, email12@foo.com` |
| 2 | Test2 | `email21@foo.com, email22@foo.com` |

Any clue on how I can concat the XML email node values as a column along the related columns (Id and Label)?
Thanks ahead

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
select ID, Label,
    stuff(
        details.query('for $step in /terms/destination/email/text() return concat(", ", string($step))')
        .value('.', 'nvarchar(max)'),
    1, 2, '')
from @tbl;
```

Answer (score 1):

Please try the following solution.

Because DDL and sample data population were not provided,
assumption is that the **Details** column is of XML data type.

**SQL**

```
-- DDL and sample data population, start
DECLARE @tbl TABLE (ID INT IDENTITY PRIMARY KEY, Label VARCHAR(20), Details XML);
INSERT INTO @tbl (Label, Details) VALUES
('Test1',N'<terms><destination><email>email11@foo.com</email><email>email12@foo.com</email></destination><content>blabla</content></terms>'),
('Test2',N'<terms><destination><email>email21@foo.com</email><email>email22@foo.com</email></destination><content>blabla</content></terms>');
-- DDL and sample data population, end

SELECT ID, Label 
    , REPLACE(Details.query('data(/terms/destination/email/text())').value('.','VARCHAR(MAX)'), SPACE(1), ', ') AS Destination
FROM @tbl;
```

**Output**

```
+----+-------+----------------------------------+
| ID | Label |           Destination            |
+----+-------+----------------------------------+
|  1 | Test1 | email11@foo.com, email12@foo.com |
|  2 | Test2 | email21@foo.com, email22@foo.com |
+----+-------+----------------------------------+
```